# urls with DRF DefaultRouter. How to add a prefix?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework to setup a RESTful API for my webapp. The problem is that I need to keep trace of edited content and to review them before publish. So I came up with creating two models (for instance `Note` and `NoteEdit`). This is working quite fine but in `urls.py` I need to handle urls so if they match `/api/edits/notes/` they are routered to `NoteEditViewSet` and if they match `/api/notes/` they are routered to `NoteViewSet`.

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from api_v1 import views
    
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'notes', views.NoteViewSet)
    
    
edits_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'notes', views.NoteEditViewSet)
    
urlpatterns = [
    path('edits/', include(edits_router.urls)),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

This is not working. Why?

Comment: What you mean by `not working`? Are you facing any errors? If so, please share traceback. You are not getting expected output? If so, what should that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoteEditViewSet` is still registered to `router`. Change it to:

```py
edits_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
edits_router.register(r'notes', views.NoteEditViewSet)
# ^^^ change to this
```

Comment: Guess it's time to take a break.

Comment: Never a bad idea ;)